# Weird error while using realloc

Tags: c++, realloc

I am running below code and i am getting output as 8 0 4, rather 8 9 4. Can you please help me understand the problem with this code-

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() { 
    int *p;

    p = (int*)calloc(2, sizeof(int));

    *(p + 0) = 8;
    *(p + 1) = 9;

    p = (int*)realloc(p, 3);

    *(p + 2) = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cout << p[i] << " ";

    free(p);
    p = NULL;
}
```

Comment: `realloc(p,3)` --> `realloc(p,3*sizeof(int))`

Comment: 1) Format this mess! 2) Don't spam tags. This is C++, not C. 3) Undefined behaviour. RTFM! 4) Don't use C-style memory allocation in C++. Don't use C-style coding in C++. If you want C, write C code! 5) Use array-notation, not pointer arithmetics. Don't obfuscate your code.

Comment: @Olaf: I agree 100%.  Btw, what is C++ equivalent of `realloc()` ?

Comment: @chqrlie: I don't program in C++. But the standard lib should provide something.

Comment: @chqrlie `std::vector<int>::resize()`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: thank you for the reference. This is not as general as it only applies to vectors, not arrays allocated with `new[]`, but I guess these are out of fashion. Interestingly, C++ does let you reduce memory footprint for the vector: *Vector capacity is never reduced when resizing to smaller size because that would invalidate all iterators, rather than only the ones that would be invalidated by the equivalent sequence of pop_back() calls.*  `realloc()` is a notorious source of bugs as well, very error prone.

Comment: @chqrlie -- A `vector` is essentially a wrapper for `new[]`.  The vector stores its data in contiguous memory, no different than if you used `new[]` and a pointer.  The difference of course is that vector handles all of these details, knows how to properly clean up when it goes out of scope, etc.

Comment: [Usage of vector equivalent to OP's program](http://ideone.com/CSch0M).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: of course, old style C++ should be deprecated and C style allocation removed. It is just too bad the syntax is so unpalatable.

Comment: @chqrlie You are looking at the syntax through biased eyes, since you're used to C.  Beginners to C++ who have no experience in C usually  find nothing wrong with the syntax.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: You should post an answer with your code as a suggestion. Some people might think it is off topic, but I teaching newbies good practices is useful.

Answer (score 1):

[The `realloc` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) needs the size on *bytes* and not elements.

You need to do

```
int *temp = realloc(p, 3 * sizeof(*temp));
if (temp == NULL)
{
    // Handle error...
}
p = temp;
```

Note that I use a temporary variable for the result of [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc). This is because if [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) fails it will return `NULL` and reassigning the result back to the pointer you pass as the first argument then you will lose the original pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The size specified as an argument to `realloc()` must be computed as a number of bytes.  As you found out yourself, the simple fix is

```
p = (int*)realloc(p, 3 * sizeof(int));
```

Incidentally, you could use the type of `*p` instead of `int` to avoid potential inconsistencies if the type of `p` changes later:

```
p = (int*)realloc(p, 3 * sizeof(*p));
```

But since the cast is needed in C++, the inconsistency at least be visible.
You should also test whether `calloc()` and `realloc()` succeeded.  They do not throw exception but return `NULL` when out of memory.

Note that you should decide whether you program in C or C++.  These languages have a common ancestry but have diverged notably and some idioms used in one are considered bad style in the other, as more appropriate and safer constructs are available.

Here is a corrected version of your program in C:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) { 
    int *p = calloc(2, sizeof(*p));
    assert(p != NULL);

    *(p + 0) = 8;
    *(p + 1) = 9;

    p = realloc(p, 3 * sizeof(*p));
    assert(p != NULL);

    *(p + 2) = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d ", p[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

While here is C++ program by PaulMcKenzie that implements the same thing, although the use of pointer `p` is still frowned upon:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() { 
    std::vector<int> pV(2);
    int *p = pV.data();
    *(p + 0) = 8;
    *(p + 1) = 9;
    pV.resize(3);
    p = pV.data();
    *(p + 2) = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << p[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

As you can see, `std::vector<int>::resize()` takes the number of elements, no need to compute byte counts.

Using pointers and especially pointer arithmetic is not good practice in C++, a much simpler version is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() { 
    std::vector<int> v(2);
    v[0] = 8;
    v[1] = 9;
    v.resize(3);
    v[2] = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

You could also use an enumerator for the printout.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I got the problem:

```
p = (int*)realloc(p, 3);
```

the size value I had specified was `3`, it should have been `3 * sizeof(int)`